# Weird SQL Behavior, why is this query returning nothing?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, unicode, unicode-string

Assume there is a table named "myTable" with three columns:

```
{**ID**(PK, int, not null), 
 **X**(PK, int, not null), 
 **Name**(nvarchar(256), not null)}.
```

Let {4, 1, аккаунт} be a record on the table.

```
select * from myTable as t 
    where t.ID=4  
    AND t.X = 1 
    AND (     t.Name = N'аккаунт'  )

select * from myTable as t 
    where t.ID=4  
    AND t.X = 1 
    AND (  t.Name LIKE N'%аккаунт%'  )
```

The first query return the record, however, the second does not? Why?

Systems where this issues are experienced:

*Windows XP - Professional - Version 2002 - SP3
*Server Collation:* Latin1_General_CI_AS
*Version:* 9.00.3073.00
*Level:* SP2
*Edition:* Developer Edition

*Sever Collation:* SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
*Version:* 9.00.3054.00
*Level:* SP2
*Edition:* Enterprise Edition

Results:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('SQLCharSetName')
iso_1

Using OSQL.exe
0x30043A043A04300443043D04420400000000000000000000000000000000
0x3F3F3F3F3F3F3F0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x253F3F3F3F3F3F3F25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

SELECT CAST(name AS BINARY),
       CAST(N'аккаунт' AS BINARY),
       CAST(N'%аккаунт%' AS BINARY)
FROM   myTable t
WHERE  t.ID = 4  
       AND t.X = 1

CAST(name AS BINARY) 
0x30043A043A04300443043D04420400000000000000000000000000000000  
CAST(N'аккаунт' AS BINARY)
0x3F3F3F3F3F3F3F0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  
CAST(N'%аккаунт%' AS BINARY)
0x253F3F3F3F3F3F3F25000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a great deal of research, I found it is indeed a problem found on the following versions of SQL Server 2005:

Windows XP - Professional - Version 2002 - SP3
Version: 9.00.3073.00
Level: SP2
Edition: Developer Edition

Version: 9.00.3054.00
Level: SP2
Edition: Enterprise Edition

..may be other versions as well.

FIX: Upgrade to SP3.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please post the result of the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(name AS BINARY),
       CAST(N'аккаунт' AS BINARY),
       CAST(N'%аккаунт%' AS BINARY)
FROM   myTable t
WHERE  t.ID = 4  
       AND t.X = 1
```

This will help to narrow the problem down.

**UPDATE:**

As I can see from the results of your query, you have a problem with encoding.

The Cyrillic literals from your string constants are being converted to the question marks (`0x3F`).

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this behavior with `Management Studio` on my test server.

I reckon there is some problem with `OS` settings, as Cyrillic characters most probably don't even reach `SQL Server`.

Could you please answer three more questions:

1. What `OS` are you using (version, language, `MUI` if any)

   - What does this query return:

     SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('SQLCharSetName')
   - Connect to your server using `osql.exe` and issue this query:

     SELECT CAST(name AS BINARY),
            CAST(N'аккаунт' AS BINARY),
            CAST(N'%аккаунт%' AS BINARY)
     FROM   myTable t
     WHERE  t.ID = 4
            AND t.X = 1
     GO

   What does it return being run in `osql.exe`?

Comment: You can see the results now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This queries dont work right off Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 9.00.3042.00

Comment: I've added the information you requested. Thanks for the help. Ive learned a couple things from you already. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, but unfortunately I still cannot reproduce your problem. I don't have a SQL Server with ISO_1 server encoding handy, and on SQL Server 2005 Russian everything of course works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries return the same result for me.

```
select * from myTable as t
where t.ID=4
AND t.X = 1
AND (t.Name = N'аккаунт')
```

Returns:

```
ID          X           Name
----------- ----------- ------------
4           1           аккаунт
```

And

```
select * from myTable as t
where t.ID=4
AND t.X = 1
AND (t.Name LIKE N'%аккаунт%')
```

Returns:

```
ID          X           Name
----------- ----------- ------------
4           1           аккаунт
```

(1 row(s) affected)

My version of SQL Server is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3077.00 (Intel X86) 
    Dec 17 2008 15:19:45 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition on Windows NT 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)
```

My collation is set to: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

My results for Quassnoi:
`0x30043A043A04300443043D04420400000000000000000000000000000000`
`0x30043A043A04300443043D04420400000000000000000000000000000000`
`0x250030043A043A04300443043D0442042500000000000000000000000000`

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: This results are expected. @Newbie's Cyrillic literal are converted into question marks, he most probably has some problems with encoding on client side.

Comment: Could you please tell what version of SQL server you are using. Thanks!